# Existence of isomorphism between tensor products.

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

In multilinear algebra many maps are usually proven to exist rather than simply defined. For example, commutativity is one such example. In the book I'm studying the author says: let $V_1,\dots,V_k$ be a collection of vector spaces over $K$, then if $\sigma \in S_k$ there is a linear isomorphism

$$f_\sigma : V_1\otimes\cdots\otimes V_k\to V_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes V_{\sigma(k)}$$

such that $f_\sigma(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_k)=v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(k)}$. Then to show this, he defines

$$g : V_1\times\cdots\times V_k\to V_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes V_{\sigma(k)}$$

by $g(v_1,\dots,v_k)=v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(k)}$. He argues then that $g$ is multilinear and by the universal property there is a linear $f_\sigma$ such that

$$f_\sigma(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_k)=v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(k)}$$

and since this turns basis into basis is isomorphism.

That's pretty fine, I understand this proof, I just don't understand the need for it. Why do we need to show that $f_\sigma$ exists this way? Couldn't we simply say: pick $f_\sigma$ defined on the factorizable tensors by

$$f_\sigma(v_1\otimes\cdots \otimes v_k)=v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(k)}$$

and extend by linearity. Then $f_\sigma$ is linear, turn basis into basis and is isomorphism.

Why do we need to first define a multilinear map, then show that $f_\sigma$ exists using the universal property? This just *one* example, there are many others where the same thing happens (associativity, existance of tensor product of linear maps and so on).

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because not everything you can formally write down is an actual linear map, or even well defined. Consider the following example:

Define $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}f : \RR \otimes \RR \to \RR$ by $$f(x \otimes y) = x + y$$ Sounds reasonable, right? Think again... Because this map is not well defined! Indeed, $f((1+1) \otimes 1) = (1+1)+1 = 3$. But $(1+1) \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes 1$, and if you wanted to extend by linearity, you would find $f(1 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes 1) = f(1 \otimes 1) + f(1 \otimes 1) = 2+2 = 4$.

So to define a map on a tensor product, you really have to check multilinearity. Once you're sufficiently accustomed to tensor products, you can skip this step, but until then, I advise you to always check multilinearity.

Comment: I see the problem now. So, instead of defining $f_\sigma$ and then checking it's linear, we simply use the universal property to check linearity of $f_\sigma$ more directly? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, it's partially that. The other problem is that you cannot necessarily directly define $f_\sigma$ directly.